# Firestore + App Engine for realtime updates possible?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

[This documentation link for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine#listening_to_real-time_events_from_a_web_browser) outlines an example where app engine listens to a RealTime Database reference.

I was wondering if

1. This can be done equivalently with Firestore using .onSnapshot
2. Whether I can specify wildcards in the reference as I do with cloud function triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No

There are no wildcard listeners with the Firestore SDK.  Cloud Functions is responding to events generated by Firestore, which is very different than how a listener in the SDK works.

Comment: I see. Do cloud functions implement a wrapper around the firestore events that passes wildcard variables to the cloud function? Seems possible to manually implement by parsing the snapshot. Can you confirm?

Comment: No, there is no wrapper.  It's a completely different infrastructure, and it can't be fully duplicated by a client SDK.